# Emacs auto-complete via ELPA

Tags: emacs24

I've just installed via elpa auto-complete 1.4 and I can see the directory in my .emacs.d/elpa/ folder. Now what do I do? I've tried various .emacs lines, but I'm never sure what an elpa install really does and what I would still need to do to my .emacs file. AFA Emacs is concerned, it can't find auto-complete. I saw this on another install:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")  
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "/home/memyselfi/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode)
(require 'auto-complete)
```

. . . but this doesn't work. Actually, I'd like auto-complete to do the advance guess/autocomplete in the minibuffer, as when it suggests files, commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

auto-complete does not do fuzzy matching in the minibuffer.

You probably want to enable ido-mode.

Try putting this in your init.el

```
(ido-mode t) ;; auto-completes file-names etc
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t) ;; enables fuzzy matching
```

There are other packages that do this, but ido-mode comes standard with Emacs, so is probably easiest to get going.